# Having different versions of source code with some common and some different content in git

Tags: android, git, version-control

I know this sounds a little bit odd but I'm really struggling with this situation and `git branching` is not the answer.

I have a situation that I need to keep my android source code in different versions. But the problem is some part of the code is common in these versions but some are not since they are files and edits based on different android market standards; they need to be different.

So I need to find a way to keep my source code in different versions and as I'm editing code, these common differences take effect in all versions but as I'm editing the different files and contents (Ones related to the markets) I need them to only effect and be added to their own version.

P.S: I cannot use git branching since I need to keep track of each and every version changes with commons and differences all the time and its not a logical approach cause it may cause problems.

P.S: I need to find a way to configure something like `gitignore` to approach this task and make git push commons and differences to their related versions.

P.S: If any other VCS or program helps to approach this I'd be glad to know.

Comment: Are these changes something that can't be handled using typical localization and/or application profile techniques commonly used?

Answer (score 1):

Use different projects.  Make your common parts a library, and then make different projects which include that library.  Then you can have it in one repository.  Alternatively, you can put them in different repositiories and use a git submodules to link between them.

Answer (score 0):

Git branching can meet your requirements.

Assume there are two market standards you need to work on, so you can manage your source code in three branches:

- `common` branch: manage the versions for the common files. With `.gitignore` to match all the possible non common files so other branches merged in the `common` branch, the non common files won’t be tracked.
- `market1` branch: manage all the source code in market1 standard. And the non common files for market1 standard only managed in `market1` branch.
- `market2` branch: manage all the source code in market2 standard. And the non common files for market2 standard only managed in `market2` branch.

The workflow shoule be:

- When changes made on `common` branch, if you want to update the common files in the different markets branches, you can merge `common` branch directly into the markets branches separately.
- Develop and manage the versions of the non common files about market1 standard in `market1` branch. If you changed the common files in  `market1` branch, you can update the version in common branch by merging `market1` branch into `common` branch (the non common files won’t be added in common branch since it’s match in `.gitignore`).
- Develop and manage the versions of the non common files about market2 standard in `market2` branch. If you changed the common files in  `market2` branch, you can update the version in `common` branch by merging `market2` branch into `common` branch.

Comment: How can I create gitignore differently for each branch ?
cause files from market 1 and market 2 are in common branch's gitignore but has to be added and committed in market branches.
P.S: And what about the files common in all three branches with only a few differences in some lines (like android manifest)

Comment: It's unnecessary to create `.gitignore` for each branch, only ignore non common files in `common` branch is enough. Since `common` branch is used for record versions for the common files, so when you merge `common` branch into market branches, it's only need to merge the common files into market branches.

Comment: And no matter what's the differences among the three branches (a few lines or lots of files), you can merge the branches as the workflow.

Comment: But the point is I never want to merge my common branch to markets. just want the versions separately. To both keep track of each version and don't miss up any of the market branches to commons. because it may cause future problems for the other market branch since common is merged with uncommon files and lines.

Comment: If you want to manage the versions for common files, non common files for market1 standard, non common files for market2 standard separately, you can also use git submodule or git subtree. So what do you real need to manage these files, **in separate branches** or **in separate repos and treat the relation as main-submodule**?

Comment: If you want to manage the code in separate branches in the same repo, merge operation is necessary, and you can still manage the versions separately in each branch even after merges. Details about git branching and mering, you can refer https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging.